# It compiles in Swift... but what is it?

Tags: swift

I mistakenly typed something like this in Swift:

```
var a = [Int, Int, Int]()
```

and it compiles... but I have no clue what this can represent...

Any ideas? Can someone explain the semantic meaning of it?

Thanks, happy coding to all,

Comment: Whenever you are unsure what type is being inferred just alt+click on variable name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an array of tuples of type `(Int, Int, Int)` Consider the following:

```
var a = [Int, Int, Int]()
a.append(12, 1134, 124)
var first = a.first!
first.0 //= 12
first.1 //= 1134
first.2 //= 124
```

Comment: The lack of parentheses got me :) thanks for the answer.